# HTTP request with axios in NodeJS not able to change header format

Tags: node.js, axios

I have an API that accepts headers as list of strings formatted as:

```
headers: [
    "Content-Type: application/json"
]
```

Unfortunately I'm not finding a way to send the headers this way in axios as they get formatted into a map structure like so:

```
headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

The map structure is obviously the better structure, but I have to support the limitations of existing systems. Is there any way to change this formatting in axios?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```js
const headersList = {
    "Content-Type: application/json"
};

axios.post(url, data, {
    headers: headersList
})
```

Comment: I tried to do exactly that, but it ends up getting formatted like so: {"0":"Content-Type: application/json","1":"Accept: application/json","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*", "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","User-Agent":"axios/0.19.0","Content-Length":323}

Not sure what in axios' code is converting this string[] into an object?